# different represents of complex functions

Tags: complex-analysis

For any one variable complex function, $f(z)$, we have four cases:

1. complex variable of real valued
2. real variable of real valued
3. complex variable of complex valued
4. real variable of complex valued

And as well know, there are two typical represent of complex functions:

(1) $f(z)=u(z)+iv(z)$

(2)$f(z)=u(x,y)+iv(x,y)$

As I understand, in case (2), $u,v\in C(\mathbb{R}^2)$,but I am confusing about case (1), and what 's the difference between them?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know they are the same, I find that (1) is just a slight abuse of notation, generally I would use (2) since $u$ and $v$ are indeed functions of $C(\mathbb{R}^2,\mathbb{R})$.

As an example, take $f(z)=z^2$, then writing $z=x+iy$, we get

$f(z)=f(x+iy)=(x+iy)^2=x^2+2ixy-y^2=(x^2-y^2)+i(2xy)$,

so $u(x,y)=x^2-y^2$ and $v(x,y)=2xy$.

I hope this answers your question.